# Cancel Option GetOpenFilename(Multiselect:= True)

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following question: when I use the `GetFileOpenFileName` option with
 `Multiselect = True` it returns the results as a Array if I selected one file or more, but if I click "Cancel" it returns as a boolean vartype. What should I do to avoid the

> error 13 "Incompatible Type

when someone clicks it.

Besides, I already tried to test  `if(vartype(filename) = vbBoolean) then` or `if(filename = False) then` to exit sub, but the first one I took the same error and the second one it said that I'm not allowed to assign values to `filename` if I select some file.

Here is the code.

```
public sub open_file()
dim i as integer
Dim filename() As Variant

filename = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Arquivos em Excel", MultiSelect:=True, FileFilter:="Arquivos em Excel,*.xls*")

For i = 1 To UBound(filename)

    msgbox filename(i)

next i

end sub
```

Comment: Try `Dim filename As Variant`, then do any checking you need.

Comment: to add to the above comment, a `Variant` will become an array if one is returned from the function, and will become an `Integer` or `Boolean` all depending on what the function returns. The way you are defining it forces it to be an array.

Answer (score 0):

As per comments from both @Brian M Stafford and @braX, your code should be amended as follows...

```
Public Sub open_file()

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim filename As Variant

    filename = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Arquivos em Excel", MultiSelect:=True, FileFilter:="Arquivos em Excel,*.xls*")

    If Not IsArray(filename) Then
        MsgBox "User cancelled!", vbExclamation 'optional
        Exit Sub
    End If

    For i = 1 To UBound(filename)
        MsgBox filename(i)
    Next i

End Sub
```

To clarify, notice that `filename` is declared as `Variant`, not as an array whose elements are a `Variant` data type.

As such, `filename` can be assigned either an array containing the filenames when one or more files are selected, or a boolean value when the user cancels.

Also notice that we test whether `filename` is an array to determine whether the user has selected one or more files.  If not, it exits the sub.  Otherwise, it continues.

Comment: You explained perfectly, thank you so much. It worked.