# Cancel reading a file VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have this code that'll let the user choose a file from his pc and then parse it in excel, It works fine but in case I click cancel (i choose no file ) it returns an error creating an emty sheet, How do i do so it'll just cancel the whole process .

```
Public Sub Lecturee()
Dim ws As Worksheet, strFile As String

Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add
strFile = Application.GetOpenFilename("Text Files (*.csv),*.csv", , "Please selec text file...")
With ws.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="TEXT;" & strFile, _
Destination:=ws.Range("A1"))
    .TextFilePlatform = 65001
    .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
    .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
    .Refresh
End With
  ws.name = "Lecture"
MsgBox "fichier ouvert"
End Sub
```

Comment: Before you add querytable, do a check if `strFile <> False`. `strFile = False` if you press cancel

Comment: @RaymondWu thank youu , I did whats below in the answer section, The problem is that it still creates an empty sheet

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub Lecturee()
Dim ws As Worksheet, strFile As Variant
strFile = Application.GetOpenFilename("CSV Files (*.csv),*.csv", , "Please selec text file...")
If strFile <> False Then
MsgBox "fichier ouvert" & strFile
Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add
With ws.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="TEXT;" & strFile, _
Destination:=ws.Range("A1"))
    .TextFilePlatform = 65001
    .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
    .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
    .Refresh
End With
ws.name = "Lecture"
Else: strFile = False
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I'd move both the `strfile =` and `if strfile` above the `Set ws =` so no sheet is added if no file is picked.

Comment: I would suggest to add error handling and simply ignore this error. `If Err.Number = xxx Then ...`

Comment: @Damian its returning an incompatibility error at the line if  strfile <> False , any idea why

Comment: @Chayma You probably need to declare strfile as variant, see this link - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61448379/cancel-option-getopenfilenamemultiselect-true

Comment: @RaymondWu Exactly, Ty !